# Отключить (не убрать!) прокрутку при наведении на элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, прокрутка

На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. 
Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?

Решения через добавление в нужный момент телу сайта свойств:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

или:

```
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

мне не подходят. Причина в том, что в обоих случаях место, где находится полоса прокрутки, визуально изменяется, что привлекает внимание пользователя.
Ранее сталкивался с одним JS плагином для создания кастомных полос прокрутки, в нем данная проблема была устранена. Подозреваю, что это можно сделать не слишком громоздко, а главное - чтобы было кроссбраузерно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В том самом плагине скорее всего использовалось именно `overflow: hidden;`, ведь плагин сам реализует сколлинг.

Вернемся к проблеме. Единственный способ который мне приходи на ум, реализовать простой аналог системной прокрутки, но не отправлять событие прокрутки к родителю.

HTML:

```
<div class="non-scroll">
    <div class="scroll" id="scroll">
        <div class="other-stuff"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.non-scroll{
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: green;
}

.scroll{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

.other-stuff{
    height: 2000px;
}
```

JS:

```
var scroll = document.getElementById("scroll");

scroll.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(e) {
    this.scrollTop -= (e.wheelDeltaY || (e.originalEvent && (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta)) || e.wheelDelta || 0);
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

По моему личному мнению это **очень плохая идея**, жертвовать нативным скроллом ради избавления от этого небольшого "прыжка". Однако я сомневаюсь что существуют способы проще.

*Все подобные вопросы на английском SO. Так же приходят к довольно костыльным решениям.*

В любом случае, вот: [живое демо](https://jsfiddle.net/gmopm892/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('main').addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  var main = e.currentTarget

  if (e.deltaY > 0
    ? main.scrollTop + main.clientHeight >= main.scrollHeight
    : e.deltaY < 0 && !main.scrollTop
  ) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  width: 25em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

main {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: auto;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?

<main>
  На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
  На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
  На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
  На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
</main>

На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
```

Answer (score 0):

Если позволяет поддержка браузерами, то это делается одним css-свойством:

```
overscroll-behavior: contain;
```

Пример целиком:

```css
body {
  width: 25em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

main {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: auto;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?

<main>
  На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
  На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
  На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
  На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
</main>

На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
На странице есть блок с собственным скроллингом (реализован без JS плагинов). Проблема в том, что когда пользователь долистывает прокрутку в блоке до конца, если и дальше крутить колесико, начинает скроллиться вся страница. Как заставить браузер "тормозить" по достижении конца блока и не скроллить дальше?
```